# Identifying Unicode replacement characters (U+FFFD or � or black diamond question mark) in R

Tags: r, text, character-encoding, gsub, grepl

I have data from a large Qualtrics survey that was processed in Stata before I got it. I'm now trying to clean up the data in R. Some of the Portuguese characters have been replaced with �. I'm trying to flag text entry responses to a series of questions that were originally "não" ["no" in English] and are now recorded as "n�o". I can see in tests below that gsub() and grepl() can identify "�" in both a list or data frame, but when I try to use the same commands on the the real data, both commands fail to identify "n�o" and even "�". There is no error; it just fails to substitute for gsub() and marks FALSE when it should be TRUE for grepl().

Are there multiple types of � based on the underlying character? Is there some way to search for or replace � characters that will pick up any instance?

This example shows that gsub() and grepl() both work fine on a list or data frame:

```
list <- c("n�o ç não", "n�o", "nao", "não")
gsub("�", "ã", list)
grepl("�", list)

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(list)
df.new <- df %>%
  mutate(
    sub = gsub("�", "ã", df$list),
    replace = grepl("�", list))
df.new$sub
df.new$replace
```

[1] "não ç não" "não"       "nao"       "não"
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

[1] "não ç não" "não"       "nao"       "não"
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

This same code fails to identify "�" in my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are on a windows machine, which sometimes doesn't play nice with unicode characters. To re-create im parsing your actual post to show you what you can do. I suggest using the `stringi` library, and using to replace all the characters that you know to be `ã` as a short-cut, but really you'd want to handle each possible-case with a blanket solution. Checkout `?stringi-search-charclass` for more info on how to do this, but.. from your original post:

> I have data from a large Qualtrics survey that was processed in Stata before I got it. I'm now trying to clean up the data in R. Some of the Portuguese characters have been replaced with �. I'm trying to flag text entry responses to a series of questions that were originally "não" ["no" in English] and are now recorded as "n�o". I can see in tests below that gsub() and grepl() can identify "�" in both a list or data frame, but when I try to use the same commands on the the real data, both commands fail to identify "n�o" and even "�". There is no error; it just fails to substitute for gsub() and marks FALSE when it should be TRUE for grepl().

We get:

```
library(xml2)
library(stringi)
this_post = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540384/identifying-unicode-replacement-characters-ufffd-or-or-black-diamond-questio#66540384"
read_html(this_post) %>% 
    xml_find_all('//*[@id="question"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]') %>% 
        xml_text() %>% stri_replace_all_regex("\\p{So}", "ã")
```

> I have data from a large Qualtrics survey that was processed in Stata before I got it. I'm now trying to clean up the data in R. Some of the Portuguese characters have been replaced with ã. I'm trying to flag text entry responses to a series of questions that were originally "não" ["no" in English] and are now recorded as "não". I can see in tests below that gsub() and grepl() can identify "ã" in both a list or data frame, but when I try to use the same commands on the the real data, both commands fail to identify "não" and even "ã". There is no error; it just fails to substitute for gsub() and marks FALSE when it should be TRUE for grepl().

### For your original data... see if this works:

```
stringi::stri_escape_unicode(orig_data)  %>% 
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\\p{So}", "ã")
```

### One-more thing

You cannot `grepl` with the unknown-char, because the function has no idea what you are asking it to match, instead try this:

```
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode("\\u00e3")
[1] "ã"
grepl("\u00e3", stringi::stri_escape_unicode(orig_data), perl = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

### EDIT based on comment:

Below is a good solution, as the "question mark" chars you were getting are likely lost as a result of being ascii. **NOTE** that in the example I gave, you would merely be replacing ANY/ALL bad-chars with the "ã". Obviously this isn't a good approach, but if you read the help docs i am sure you'll see how you can use this approach blended with an escape to work for all your strings.

```
orig_data$repaired_text <- stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(orig_data$text)  %>%      stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\\p{So}", "ã")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You are correct that I'm on Windows. The code above gave an error and suggested the alternative below, which worked well on a column-by-column basis.         

`orig_data$repaired_text <- stringi::stri_enc_toutf8(orig_data$text)  %>% 
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\\p{So}", "ã")` Would you like to edit the response to reflect this, so I can accept the answer? Also, would you mind elaborating a little on whether this code should work for all "�" or just that which is placeholding for "ã"? Thanks again.

Comment: I had no way of knowing there was an `orig_data$text` I was just giving an example, but looks like you're getting there!

Comment: I only added that to make it clear to others that the code would operate on one column in a data frame at a time, as opposed to finding and replacing all instances in the data frame. Thanks again, and nice work scraping the post text as example text. That's a cool maneuver. I'll upvote when I get enough reputation.

Comment: no problem, I would have gone into more detail, but my brain was fried... was working through an issue at work. If you'd like me to go into more detail just let me know.